# Select multiple entries in SQLite where multiple rows need to match the same condition (including AND, OR and NOT)

Tags: c#, sqlite, constraints, operations

I have a question regarding selecting in SQLite. I have given entries in a DB, where i need to select all rows which match my criterion. These criterion can be combined with AND, OR or NOT.

For example, I have

```
     id  |  image  |  tag
    -----|---------|------
     21  |     21  |   35
     25  |    240  |   45
     36  |     21  |   40
     43  |    155  |   35
     56  |    243  |   35
     65  |    312  |   40
```

as data in my DB.

What I want to do now, is to search for example for all entries with the tag 35. So far so easy (simple SELECT query).
This gives me the images *21*, *155* and *243*.

1. But now, I want every entry with the tag 35, BUT ONLY the ones, that have 40 as tag as well. This would be a **AND** constrain.

   - This would result in only *21*
2. Besides from an *AND* constrain, I want also to search for entries, which have a tag of 35, BUT ALSO for the ones with a tag of 40 (an **OR** constrain).

   - This should result in the images *21*, *155*, *243* and *312*
3. Furthermore, I want to exclude some entries with a **NOT** constrain. For example, I want every entry with a tag 35, BUT NOT the ones with a tag 40.

   - The result of this would be the images *155* and *243*

How can I achieve this with SQLite-queries? I know, how to search for multiple criterion inside an entry, but I have at this time no idea, how to search over multiple entries with this constrains. I could solve this by selecting two different lists, and then *intersect*, *union* or *except* them with each other. But I think, there must be a better, direct way.

I hope, this goal can be reached, without writing horribly long queries which contain thousands of sql-statements. ;)

Does someone know, how to search for entries like described above?

Thank you in advance for your help

Kind regards
Ramon

(Please keep some of my English mistakes; there are free of charge ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using compound queries is the simplest solution:

```sql
SELECT image FROM data WHERE tag = 35
INTERSECT
SELECT image FROM data WHERE tag = 40;

SELECT image FROM data WHERE tag = 35
UNION
SELECT image FROM data WHERE tag = 40;

SELECT image FROM data WHERE tag = 35
EXCEPT
SELECT image FROM data WHERE tag = 40;
```

Using [correlated subqueries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) would also be possible:

1. All entries with tag 35 for which a row with the same image and the tag 40 exists:

   ```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM data
   WHERE tag = 35
     AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM data AS d2
                 WHERE d2.image = data.image
                   AND d2.tag = 40);
   ```
2. Nothing complicated:

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT image
   FROM data
   WHERE tag IN (35, 40);
   ```
3. All entries with tag 35 for which no row with the same image and the tag 40 exists:

   ```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM data
   WHERE tag = 35
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM data AS d2
                     WHERE d2.image = data.image
                       AND d2.tag = 40);
   ```